# Ruby on Rails - Filter records based on users selected options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filter, rails-activerecord

In my application, I have a `Book` model. I have around 10000k book records in my database. Basically, the application works as the user can select *options* and get a list of books that *matches* their inserted credentials.

Each of these `books`  has `type`, `language` & `genres`.

Each book can have several `type`, `language` & `genres` *(like an array)*

```
title: 'Have fun book' 
type: ['pdf', 'paper', 'website']
language: ['Egnlish', 'French', 'German', 'Spanish']
genres: ['comedy']
```

My `BooksController`:

```
def book_params
  params.require(:book).permit(type:[], language:[], genres:[])
end
```

The form where the user can insert their credentials and filter the books looks like the picture below:

[image: Book filter form]

Currently, this is what I'm doing in my `BooksController` to *filter* the books:

```
@book_filter = Book
                .where(type: @book.type)
                .where(language: @book.language)
                .where(genres: @book.genres)
```

This works kind of fine, but I have a few issues with it. If for example, the user doesn't select any **Book type/ `type`** or any other option, instead of getting `all`, I get `nil` and for that reason, no books are shown to the user.

What I have in mind is that if the option wasn't selected, either `where` for that options doesn't get *affected* or it passes `all`.

I tried this with no luck:

```
@book_filter = Book
                .where(type: @book.type || '')
                .where(language: @book.language || '')
                .where(genres: @book.genres || '')
```

My second issue is that I feel the filter could be written much smarter & *Rails way*.

Thanks in advance and any help is appreciated!

*Rails 5.1*

Comment: Move the filter to a variables `@book_filter = Book.all` and then filter accordingly: `@book_filter = @book_filter.where(type: @book.type) if @book.type.present?`, etc..

Comment: and btw, how are you storing the types and languages ? are you using `array` fields in `PostgreSQL` ?

Comment: Thanks @RocKhalil This could work if I only checked `@book.type` but there would be several others as well such as language, generes and 2-3 more, and I think thats why I can't just use `@book_filter.where(type: @book.type) if @book.type.present?` since there would be other `where` and conditions as well. and yes I use `array` to store them

Comment: yes, you have to do: `@book_filter = @book_filter.where(type: @book.type) if @book.type.present?`, `@book_filter = @book_filter.where(language: @book.language) if @book.language.present?`, `@book_filter = @book_filter.where(genres: @book.genres) if @book.genres.present?`; I would also suggest to move them to models (`Type`, `Languages` and `Genre`) and have `many_to_many` relations; this is the `Rails Way` that you're asking about :-p

Comment: Thanks @RocKhalil. I think that would work in some way, but no the Rails way I would think :P moving them to models could also be an option but that would require extra "stuff" that I don't think its needed here :P because than for a book it would have over 6-7 tables and all connected with `many_to_many`. I think it would be a overkill

Comment: What are the semantics of the search? If a book has more languages/types/genres than specified in the search, should it match? What about if only one of the languages from the search matches?

Comment: Thanks, @ma_il Regarding the book and languages, each book/record will only have one language, but type and would be an array. So to give you an example, If the search was, Books that are in `genres`: Comedy, Horror & `language`: English, French & `type`: PDF, Only books that have these options would be selected. So the books would be in `genres`: Comedy or Horror & `language`: English, French & `type:` pdf. So if there is book that matches both `genres` & `language`, but not the language, it won't be selected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `models/concerns` create a `module`:

```
module Filterable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def filter(filtering_params)
      results = self.where(nil)
      filtering_params.each do |key, value|
        results = results.public_send(key, value) if value.present?
      end
      results
    end
  end
end
```

Include the `module` in your `model` as below:

```
class Product
  include Filterable
  ...
end
```

Then in your controller do:

```
@products = Product.filter(params.slice(:status, :location, :starts_with))
```

private

```
# A list of the param names that can be used for filtering the Product list
def filtering_params(params)
  params.slice(:status, :location, :starts_with)
end
```

The reason behind the `module` is because this code is reusable and can be used in any part of your application.

*PS: Please keep in mind variables or models are not the same as the question but the solution is a general solution that can be implemented to any application.*

Answer (score 0):

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/54401841/3058437 but replacing `public_send` for `where` worked for me. Rails 5

```
module Filterable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def filter(filtering_params)
      results = self.where(nil)
      filtering_params.each do |key, value|
        results = results.where("#{key} = ?", value) if value.present?
      end
      results
    end
  end
end
```